# Better way to implement a shake animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a "shake animation" using jQuery.  The idea is that you can make an element shake to draw attention to it.  Below is what I came up with:

```
    function DrawAttention(item, count)
    {
        $(item).animate({top: '+=5'}, 50,
            function(){
                $(item).animate({top: '-=10'}, 100,
                    function(){
                       $(item).animate({top: '+=5'}, 50,
                            function(){
                                if(count>0)
                                {
                                    DrawAttention(item,count-1);
                                }
                            }); 
                    });
            });

    }
```

I thought this was a little verbose and was wondering if anyone can see a more elegant way to achieve what I want.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uaWkj/).

Comment: btw in your js-fiddle example you passed the jquery object $("#item") into your DrawAttention method and wrapped it a second time with jquery, you just needed to pass the string "#item"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function DrawAttention(item, count)
{
    $(item)
        .animate({top: '+=5'}, 50)
        .animate({top: '-=10'}, 100)
        .animate({top: '+=5'}, 50, function(){
            if(count > 0){
              DrawAttention(item,count-1);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: that method won't wait for one animation to finish before it starts the next

Comment: You are wrong, search for `chained animation` at http://api.jquery.com/animate/ . But it really did not work, i mistyped the `>` sign in the if statement. If you paste current code to the fiddle it would work.

Comment: +1, very cool, didn't know chained animations would wait for the previous one to finish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is an effect for this in the jQuery Ui (jqueryui.com). Trying this would be an alternative.

If you want to do this on your own, I would use an exponential function (like 2^-x) to calculate the shake offset.

Comment: thats not a very good shake equation http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3D2^-x

Comment: btw, I meant something like: offset=Math.pow(2,iterations) * (iterations%2-1);

Comment: you wrote y=2^-x, the link didnt include the ^-x. Thats more of an envelope than a shake. You need a sine to make a shake